# Error: object 'blank_theme' not found

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to plot a pie chart as below: it must be colored by the same color but with scaled intensity.

[image]

Then In my case of use, I have this data frame :

```
library(ggplot2)

régions<-c("Bouches-du-Rhône","Paris","Nord","Hauts-de-Seine",
           "Circonscription départementale du Rhône","Haute-Garonne","Bas-Rhin","Loire-Atlantique",
           "Seine-Maritime","Pas-de-Calais")


Pourcentages<-c(15.2,15.2,12.3,10.1,9.7,8.4,7.7,7.5,7.2,6.8)
length(Pourcentages)

Data<-data.frame(régions,Pourcentages)
```

And as given [here](http://www.sthda.com/french/wiki/ggplot2-graphique-en-camembert-guide-de-demarrage-rapide-logiciel-r-et-visualisation-de-donnees), I tried to plot my pie chart as given below.

```
bp<- ggplot(data, aes(x="", y=Pourcentages, fill=régions))+
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity")

pie <- bp + coord_polar("y", start=0)


pie + scale_fill_brewer("Blues") + blank_theme+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank())+
  geom_text(aes( y=Pourcentages, 
                label = Pourcentages, size=5))
```

But I get this error that I can't resolve it:

> Error: object 'blank_theme' not found

What should I do, please?

Comment: I *strongly* recommend you adhere to established norms and program in English. Meaning all your identifiers and comments in code should be English, not localised.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, it gives the same error `Error: object 'theme_blank' not found`

Comment: Have you defined `blank_theme` anywhere? If not, you can't call something that hasn't been defined. But you're asking about both the theme and the coloring of the plot—these are separate issues handled by separate functions. Which are you really trying to address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code, it works for me.

```
régions<-c("Bouches-du-Rhône","Paris","Nord","Hauts-de-Seine",
       "Circonscription départementale du Rhône","Haute-Garonne","Bas-Rhin","Loire-Atlantique",
       "Seine-Maritime","Pas-de-Calais")


Pourcentages<-c(15.2,15.2,12.3,10.1,9.7,8.4,7.7,7.5,7.2,6.8)
Data <-data.frame(régions,Pourcentages)


bp<- ggplot(Data, aes(x="", y=Pourcentages, fill=régions)) +
 geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") 

pie <- bp + coord_polar("y", start=0)
p <- pie + scale_fill_brewer("Blues") + theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: look what it does give me `Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (12): x, y, fill`

Comment: it works but it has many colors, but we need just one color scaled in function of the percentage value

Comment: @Rprogrammer the color scale is separate from the theme. If they're helping you with the theme, they might not be concerned with setting the colors how you want, since that's a separate issue

Comment: @camille, thank you camille, just I need to plot also the percentage in each zone figured in the pie chart

Comment: But that's not what you asked a question about. You asked about the theme

Answer (score 3):

`blank_theme` should be `theme_blank()`. However, this function is now defunct (and thus no longer exists). It has been replaced by `theme_bw()` or `theme_minimal()`.

Comment: Or `theme_void()`